# Retaining data on nth PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, postback

I have a webpage where I prompt user to select the class of the student. (inside the class there are student objects) After selection a listbox appears listing students in that specific class. Upon selecting the student (here comes the problem) I show the links to the student details - however I cannot retain student data on this third step.

I have in my Page_Load:

code that binds and creates the class list (but not the student list - it depends on the data selected on the class list)

and on my PostBack I have code to create the student list with the info stated in class list. I need to pull the data from the student list and use it in my specific link, but after selecting student causes PostBack, the whole PostBack procedure starts again and I lose the selected student.

Is there a way to define "only on first postback" or "only on nth postback", or is there anything else I can do to get past this or am I confined to only two states in asp.net syntax? I have tried placing bools in the code ends to create run-only-once traps, but apparently these are also destroyed on postbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to get around this would be to do the following:

- Append the class id to the query string in whatever button/link you are using to do the initial post after the class has been selected.
- On page load, read the class id from the query string.
- Conditionally databind the student control based on the class id that you retrieved from the query string.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of appending to link inside the same page.